# Is it possible to hide the Developer Email in the Chrome Webstore?

Tags: chrome-web-store

I am wondering whether it is possible to hide the email of the developer on the Chrome Webstore extension page.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this was what I got from Chrome Web Store support.

> In regards to the contact email address, it is a mandatory information to provide when you publish the chrome items and this requirement has been implemented on June 9th, 2020.
>
> 3.4 You Support Your Product. You agree to supply and maintain valid and accurate contact information that will be displayed in each product detail page on the Store and made available to users for customer support and legal purposes. For paid Products or in-app transactions, you must respond to customer support inquiries within three (3) business days, and within 24 hours to any support or Product concerns stated to be urgent by Google.
>
> Failure to provide adequate support for your Products may result in low Product ratings, less prominent product exposure, or in some cases removal from the Web Store, such as if the extension no longer functions as described.
>
> Having this said, there's no option to hide the contact email address from your listing page at the time but the Contact Email address doesn't have to be your personal email and you can change it anytime from the Developer Dashboard.

> You can edit it at the [Account] --> [Profile] --> [Contact email address] in the Developer Dashboard (*Please see the attached screenshot image).

So I changed the contact email from my personal email to my work one and now my personal email is no longer exposed.

[image]